# Create a VPC with specific network address

Tags: networking, amazon-web-services, ipv4

I was going to created a VPC but I'm confused with some questions.

The questions i asked is on the second point dot.

Scenario: You have a small business with a website that is hosted on an Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud (Amazon EC2) instance. You have customer data that is stored on a backend database server that you want to keep private. You want to use Amazon VPC to set up a VPC that meets the following requirements:

1. Not using the Launch VPC Wizard, create a new VPC, and name it s1234567 (i.e. your student ID).

• You will make two public subnets, and two private subnets. Make four subnets and give them appropriate
names.

• The first address of your network must be xx(the last fourth and third digits of your student ID, e.g.
45).xx(the last two digits of your students id, e.g. 67).0.0. Each subnet must have 256 total IPv4 addresses.

• Make sure you have one public and one private subnet in one availability zone, then the other public and
private subnet in another availability zone.

• Ensure your Public and Private subnets are associated with Route Tables that are relevantly configured.

• Ensure resources in the private subnets can access the Internet.

• Create security group to allow HTTPS and SSH Access inside the public subnets from the wider internet.

Example my student number is s1234567.

The questions is "The first address of your network must be xx(the last fourth and third digits of your student ID, e.g. 45).xx(the last two digits of your students id, e.g. 67).0.0. Each subnet must have 256 total IPv4 addresses."

Is it 4.5.6.7/16 or 4.5.6.7/24 or all wrong?

I need an explanation.

Comment: This is indeed confusing and could be interpreted in several different ways (some of which make no sense from a subnetting POV). The only person who can provide a good explanation is whoever wrote this assignment in the first place. (Or the person who's going to be grading it, because they'll stick to _their_ interpretation no matter what...)

Answer (score 0):

The question does not make sense, but can be answered anyway.   As each subnet must have 256 total IPv4 addresses you need a /24  - A /24 is a netmask of 255.255.255.0, which groups IP's in blocks of 256 [ including network and broadcast ].

A /16 would be the wrong answer because this would mean a netmask of 255.255.0.0 and have 65536 IP addresses for the subnet.